# Compositions with linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $T(x, y) = (x + 2y, x - y)$ and $U(x, y) = (x - y, 3x + y)$ be linear transformations from $R^2$ to $R^2$ Determine the transformations of the composition of $U$ with $T$ $(U ° T)$

So I can determine the standard matrices are $T =$ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$
and $U = $ $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ but I'm not sure how to use these with compositions. What is the process needed to answer the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about matrices. Composition is defined more generally, and in this case it is pretty simple to work out what it is: for every $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2$, we have
\begin{align}
(U\circ T)(x,y) &:= U(T(x,y)) \\
&= U(x+2y, x-y) \\
&= \bigg( (x+2y)- (x-y), 3(x+2y) + (x-y)\bigg) \\
&= (3y, 4x + 5y)
\end{align}
Composition just means you do one function after the other, and since you have explicit formulas for both functions, just plug them in directly (and carefully).

---

If you really want to think in terms of matrices (which I think is counterproductive here), then the matrix representation of $U\circ T$ is the product of the matrix representations of of $U$ and $T$ (all matrices calculated relative to standard bases); i.e
\begin{align}
[U\circ T] &= [U]\cdot [T] \tag{$*$}\\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& -1\\
3 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 3\\
4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If you revert back to function notation, this says $(U\circ T)(x,y) = (3y, 4x + 5y)$. Notice how this is a three step-process (which is completely unnecessary); you first have to write down the matrices of $U$ and $T$, then you have to multiply them, and then you have to "undo" the matrix of the product to figure out $U\circ T$.

Moreover, from a conceptual standpoint, you should think of matrix multiplication as being motivated by function composition; that's really why $(*)$ is true (matrix multiplication is defined in that funny way of multiplying rows and columns with the sole intention of making $(*)$ work out).

Comment: Wow, yeh that is interesting considering how many times transformations require the standard matrix, yet treating them as functions does seem easier. Thanks.